# detect when a webpage is updated

Tags: detection

There is a website (very simple) which will be updated soon and I'd like to receive an alert at the moment it changes (like a sound, a popup,...)

I guess I should send request every x minutes and compare the result with what's now but I don't know how to do that.

I don't really care about the language used, I know java, python, php, a bit of c and bash (I'm on linux)...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do it would be to combine `wget` and `cmp` with a loop in bash. When the files differ you could use `sendmail` to throw yourself an email.